# Mapnik error occurred when using command import mapnik

Tags: centos, python

I am using **centos** and installed **mapnik** on my server. I am following this tutorial http://krisarnold.com/2010/07/14/installing-mapnik-on-centos-5/

But when I test the installation by "import mapnik", it gives me following error.

```
root@dev [~]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec  7 2011, 20:48:22)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mapnik
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/mapnik/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from _mapnik import *
ImportError: libmapnik.so.0.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions and solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this.

just needed to add an entry of '/usr/local/lib64' into one of the files inside '/etc/ld.so.conf.d/'

and than ran ldconfig.

Working very well now.

Solution found on this page https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/InstallationTroubleshooting